# Laravel: get name from table users

Tags: php, laravel, pluck

I need get the name field in user table

My method in the controller:

```
public function reviewsactivity()
{
    $activity = Activity::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->pluck('id', 'name');
    return view('reviews.reviewsactivity', compact('activity', 'users'));
}
```

And the view:

```
              @foreach($activity as $actividad)
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{ $actividad->description }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $actividad->subject_type }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $actividad->user->name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $actividad->causer_type }}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($actividad->created_at)) }}</td>
                  </tr>
              @endforeach
```

The field in the Activity table: causer_id

And I have the next log:

```
 Trying to get property of non-object 
 (View: C:\laragon\www\tao\resources\views\reviews\reviewsactivity.blade.php)
```

Comment: do you have relation between `Activity` and `User` models ?

Comment: use Relationship for this. if each activity has a user, use belongsTo relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `user_id` in `activities` table referencing `users` table then you can define `belongsTo` relationship in `Activity` model

Activity Model

```
public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Now Fetch Activity with eager loading using `with('user')`

```
public function reviewsactivity()
{
    $activity = Activity::with('user')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->pluck('id', 'name');
    return view('reviews.reviewsactivity', compact('activity', 'users'));
}
```

Check Eager Loading documents here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the activity has an attached user or not first:

```
<td>{{ !is_null($actividad->user)?$actividad->user->name:'' }}</td>
```

Else you're trying to get the attribute `name` from a non-object `null` that why you're getting the message error.